# Возможности dll-файлов

Tags: java, c++, winapi, dll, native

Здрасьте. Пишу приложение а-ля Экранная лупа управляемая с мобильного телефона. Сделал мобильное приложение и сервер на Java. Через сокеты. Саму лупу пишу на winapi. Теперь встал вопрос, как с сервера Java передать данные на Winapi Лупу и запустить ее. Начитался, что через dll-ки. Но. Как? Как Лупу на winapi "засунуть" в dll, а потом еще запустить? Окей. DLL - это библиотека, как мне методы создания окон и "общения" его с windows использовать в java?

Мое winapi приложение состоит из нескольких ф-ий:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HINSTANCE hInst;                        // current instance

POINT CursorCoords;
bool mode;
HWND hWnd;
HDC hdcScreen;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow){}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance){}

int CaptureAnImage(HWND hWnd){}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow){}

void SetCursorCoords(float x, float y){}

void StartStopApp(){}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){}

INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){}
```

По сути, мне достаточно запустить две мои ф-ии SetCursorCoords и StartStopApp. Чтобы эта программа запустилась и начала работать, но запустить их надо через Java. Вопрос в том, что надо весь этот код переводить в dll? Тогда как? Если нет, то как сделать, чтобы запустить ее по-другому? И возможно ли вообще запустить Одно приложение на winapi через другое приложение на java?

Работаю с этим впервые. Кому не сложно, наведите на мысль, покажите или расскажите. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Гугл, как ни странно, откликается на эту тему за секунду кучей ссылок. Начиная с этой: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/222092 И этой: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997343/ И этой: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454697/ и ещё целым вагоном...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясните вопрос, не понятно что куда вы передаете.

Однако, общий вопрос у вас видимо в том, как связать Java и WinAPI. Для этого можно использовать [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/).

Comment: Описал проблему по подробнее.

Comment: Что делать с функциями, которые winapi требуются для корректной работы? Или мне писать java-класс, который будет эмулировать создание оконного приложения и использовать dll?

Comment: Вы можете пойти несколькими путями: 1) Самой очевидный для меня это виндовую часть (или части) писать полностью на Си++; 2) Наоборот писать все на яве а системные вызовы делать через тот же JNI; 3) Ваш вариант тоже рабочий, DLL должна быть построена вокруг хендла окна который она получает как параметр; при этом окно должно быть создано и настроено где-то снаружи; хендл должен использоваться для перехвата сообщений к этому окну и отрисовки

Comment: Для первого варианта я пару лет не писал на с++ (может пример сокетов на с++ помог бы). Второй вариант как делать я вообще без понятия впрочем, как и третий(

Comment: Примеров про сокеты тьма в яндексе, было бы желание искать. Судя по вашему тексту я понял что саму "лупу" вы сделали и осталось ее увязать с явой. И как я понимаю для работы "лупы" требуется получать текущее изображение всего монитора а для этого вы выполняете какие-то хитрые системные вызовы. Так вот, эти вызовы я и рекмендую делать через JNI.

Comment: Мне не сложно поискать, было бы время. Спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать.

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что я вытаскиваю контекст монитора и подставляю его в окно своего приложения, но все эти махинации делаются через winapi функции и типы. Как я хендл окна возвращу яве? Думаю весь день...

Comment: А стоп, вам в DLL надо поместить только функцию `CaptureImage` и передавать ей хендл окна из явы при перерисовке этого окна. Осталось только узнать как в яве получать хендл окна. Второй вариант это переделать `CaptureImage` чтобы она возвращала растр и рисовать его средствами явы. Как-то так.

Comment: Вот про хендл http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386792/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240471/windows-handle-in-java

Comment: Я тут пошукал по вашему совету и нашел это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433994/java-window-image Если все так, как тут написано, то это жестко облегчит мне задачу. Ну эт так, к сведению)